# Selected item in dropdown menu bind to textarea

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to get the text options from the dropdown QuickMessage into the text area box ("Type message here..."). The dropdown is a popup box selector used to pick a frequently used message to submit to a chat.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="form-control"
  rows="3"
   placeholder="Type message here..."></textarea>
```

```
<div class="btn-group justify-content-center"
   role="group">
<div ngbDropdown
     placement="top"
     class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-primary"
          id="quick-message"
          ngbDropdownToggle>Quick Message</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu
       aria-labelledby="quick-message">
    <button *ngFor="let quickMessage of quickMessages$ | async"
            class="dropdown-item">{{quickMessage}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS

```
 providers: [QuickMessageService]
})
export class UserInputComponent implements OnInit {
quickMessages$: Observable<string[]>;
constructor(private quickMessageService: QuickMessageService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.quickMessages$ = this.quickMessageService.quickMessages$;
 }

}
```

Service

```
this.initFakeData();
}

get quickMessages$(): Observable<string[]>{
return this._quickMessages$.asObservable();
}

private initFakeData() {
this.quickMessages = [
  `Option1`,
  `Option2`,
  `Option3`
];
this._quickMessages$.next(this.quickMessages);
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean by this: I would like to get the text options from the dropdown QuickMessage into the text area box

Comment: I would like to be able to click on the quickMessages ("Option1" etc) and upon click have them replace "Type message here..." in the textarea